# Symfony 4.3, tags:true option for redis cache pool does not implement TagAware ItemInterface

Tags: php, symfony4, redis-cache

Using symfony 4.3, I have configured a cache pool that should enable TagAwarable for caching items.
The configuration is like so:

```
framework:
cache:
    #app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: 'redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%:%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'

    pools:
        redis.cache:
            adapter: '%framework_cache_adapter%'
            provider: 'redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%:%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
            default_lifetime: '%framework_cache_lifetime%'
            tags: true
```

In the code, using Dependency Injection I retrieve the CacheInterface using the pool name and trying to tag it which throws the following exception:

> Cache item "appSettings" comes from a non tag-aware pool: you cannot
>   tag it.

The code looks like this:

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, CacheInterface $redisCache)
{
    $this->m_cache = $redisCache;
    $this->m_entityManage = $em;
}

public function getKey(string $key) : ?string
{
    $appSettings = $this->m_cache->get(self::CACHE_KEY, function (ItemInterface $item) {
        $item->expiresAfter(3600);
        $item->tag([ 'settings', 'app_cache' ]);

        return $settings;
    });

    return $appSettings[$key] ?? null;
}
```

I have tried differernt methods to no avail and do not know how to proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated how to make the item be tagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had come across same problem.
Using `\Symfony\Contracts\Cache\TagAwareCacheInterface` fixed it for me.

**EDIT**
See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33201 for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that answer in my searches.  
Using TagAwareCacheInterface instead of CacheInterface solved the issue in my case